# Prestashop capitalize customer address

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I need to capitalize all user data in Prestashop 1.6 - I've managed to get it done for name, etc. but I don't know where I can do this for the address.

My guess is AddressController's `processSubmitAddress()` method, but I cannot find where does it take the input, so I can `strotupper()` that. Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little late, but here it is. Just change the `ucfirst` for whatever you need, in this case `strotupper()`. This is for the customer's address. In same file there should be other files for different customer data. This works also for PS 1.7.2 (tested)

Go to `yourprojectfolder/classes/Address.php`

Search for `public function add($autodate = true, $null_values = false)` on line 169.

Replace :

```
public function add($autodate = true, $null_values = false)
{
    if (!parent::add($autodate, $null_values)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (Validate::isUnsignedId($this->id_customer)) {
        Customer::resetAddressCache($this->id_customer, $this->id);
    }
    return true;
}
```

With:

```
public function add($autodate = true, $null_values = false)
{
  if (!parent::add($autodate, $null_values)) {
      return false;
  }

  // Capitalize the first name
  $this->firstname = ucfirst($this->firstname);

  // Capitalize the first name
  $this->lastname = ucfirst($this->lastname);

  // Capitalize the address fields
  $this->address1 = ucfirst($this->address1);
  $this->address2 = ucfirst($this->address2);

  if (Validate::isUnsignedId($this->id_customer)) {
      Customer::resetAddressCache($this->id_customer, $this->id);
  }
  return true;
}
```

Search for `public function update($null_values = false)` on line 181.

```
Replace :



public function update($null_values = false)
{
    // Empty related caches
    if (isset(self::$_idCountries[$this->id])) {
        unset(self::$_idCountries[$this->id]);
    }
    if (isset(self::$_idZones[$this->id])) {
        unset(self::$_idZones[$this->id]);
    }

    if (Validate::isUnsignedId($this->id_customer)) {
        Customer::resetAddressCache($this->id_customer, $this->id);
    }

    return parent::update($null_values);
}
```

With:

```
public function update($null_values = false)
{
  // Empty related caches
  if (isset(self::$_idCountries[$this->id])) {
      unset(self::$_idCountries[$this->id]);
  }
  if (isset(self::$_idZones[$this->id])) {
      unset(self::$_idZones[$this->id]);
  }

  // Capitalize the first name
  $this->firstname = ucfirst($this->firstname);

  // Capitalize the first name
  $this->lastname = ucfirst($this->lastname);

  // Capitalize the address fields
  $this->address1 = ucfirst($this->address1);
  $this->address2 = ucfirst($this->address2);

  if (Validate::isUnsignedId($this->id_customer)) {
      Customer::resetAddressCache($this->id_customer, $this->id);
  }

  return parent::update($null_values);
}
```

Instead of changing the PrestaShop core. You can also use the override option.

Create the file `yourprojectfolder/override/classes/Address.php` and insert this code and save the file:

```
<?php
/**
* Fix for capitalize and submit the first letters of the name and address input fields
*
* 2007-2015 PrestaShop
*
* NOTICE OF LICENSE
*
*  @author Peter Visser <info@mark-app.com>
*/

class Address extends AddressCore
{

  public function update($null_values = false)
  {
    // Empty related caches
    if (isset(self::$_idCountries[$this->id])) {
        unset(self::$_idCountries[$this->id]);
    }
    if (isset(self::$_idZones[$this->id])) {
        unset(self::$_idZones[$this->id]);
    }

    // Capitalize the first name
    $this->firstname = ucfirst($this->firstname);

    // Capitalize the first name
    $this->lastname = ucfirst($this->lastname);

    // Capitalize the address fields
    $this->address1 = ucfirst($this->address1);
    $this->address2 = ucfirst($this->address2);

    if (Validate::isUnsignedId($this->id_customer)) {
        Customer::resetAddressCache($this->id_customer, $this->id);
    }

    return parent::update($null_values);
  }

  public function add($autodate = true, $null_values = false)
  {
    if (!parent::add($autodate, $null_values)) {
        return false;
    }

    // Capitalize the first name
    $this->firstname = ucfirst($this->firstname);

    // Capitalize the first name
    $this->lastname = ucfirst($this->lastname);

    // Capitalize the address fields
    $this->address1 = ucfirst($this->address1);
    $this->address2 = ucfirst($this->address2);

    if (Validate::isUnsignedId($this->id_customer)) {
        Customer::resetAddressCache($this->id_customer, $this->id);
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

After that reset your cache for overrides bij deleting `yourprojectfolder/cache/class_index.php`

Source: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/333935-capitalize-first-letters-of-address-input-fields-and-submit-to-database

Answer (score 0):

Lacking the help, I decided to do a little workaround - I've actually set a trigger on the database, which on insert or update transforms the specified data with SQL's `UPPER()` function.